# MySQL how to write SQL to find excessive transactions in any 15 minute windows?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, self-join

MySQL 
Lets say there is a credit card processing company.

```
create table tran(
  id int,
  tran_dt datetime, 
  card_id int,
  merchant_id int,
  amount int
);

#Customer #1 
insert into tran values(1, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 1, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(2, '2015-01-01 01:01:00', 1, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(3, '2015-01-01 01:02:00', 1, 1, 10);

#Customer #2 
insert into tran values(21, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 2, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(22, '2015-01-01 01:01:00', 2, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(23, '2015-01-01 01:02:00', 2, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(24, '2015-01-01 01:03:00', 2, 1, 10);

#Customer #3 
insert into tran values(31, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(32, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(33, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(34, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(35, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 10);
```

A report is needed of which cards have been used 3+ times in *any 15 minute window* at the same merchant.

```
SELECT t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id, count(*) 
FROM tran t1 
JOIN tran t2
  on t2.card_id=t1.card_id 
  and t2.merchant_id=t1.merchant_id 
  and t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
  and t2.id>t1.id
GROUP BY t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id
HAVING count(*)>2
```

Result

```
card_id     merchant_id     count(*)
1           1               3
2           1               6
3           1               10
```

The count is correct for the first customer, but too high for the other customers.  Where is my sql error?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0de2/1

PS Triggers not allowed.

Comment: Think about the 1st join to all the records for the lowest time, now think about the 2nd join to all the records with time above it's time.  now think about that in the context of set 2.  you'll see the error or add group_concat(card_ID) and I think you'll understand the logic error.  The SQL is right, your expectation on count is I believe is faulty

Comment: xQbert - I dont see how expectation faulty, my count of 6 and 10 are clearly not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my answer last nite (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31600308/1816093) on your related question (glad you went with my answer :>) I was just trying to find ones >2 and that was that, and described the synthetic count.

This should  fix it, tweak the interval as needed:

```
SELECT t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id,count(distinct t1.id)+1 as ChargeCount
FROM tran t1 
INNER JOIN tran t2
on t2.card_id=t1.card_id 
and t2.merchant_id=t1.merchant_id 
and t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
and t2.id>t1.id
GROUP BY t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id
HAVING ChargeCount>2;
```

24 hr:

```
SELECT t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id,count(distinct t1.id)+1 as ChargeCount
FROM tran t1 
INNER JOIN tran t2
on t2.card_id=t1.card_id 
and t2.merchant_id=t1.merchant_id 
and t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
and t2.id>t1.id
GROUP BY t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id
HAVING ChargeCount>2;
```

**Edit**:

imo (=worth 1cent), best to go with standard dates and not home grown date math. For the following reasons:

1) one may say the join is not necessary, but it is on probably **composite** indexes and they are screaming fast. If you don't have them, add them. They are useful for all your queries (plus they are thin ints). If one were to incorporate a **covering index** (id,id,datetime), you now have an access path that is resolved in the index page and does not need to go after the data page. Remember, the index page points you to the data page that still needs read (but not necessary with a carefully chosen covering index). I have seen joins with over a million rows reduced to a few seconds by using **covering indexes**.

2) home-grown date math is error prone

3) home-grown date math is hard to modify and tweak

4) shorter looking sql doesn't = faster sql. Shorter sql can just transfers the processing burden to functions that are outside of index optimization and often (dare I say more times than not) result in a tablescan. The dreaded tablescan.

Answer (score 0):

That should have the first transaction id in the `group by`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id, t1.tran_dt, count(*) 
FROM tran t1 JOIN
     tran t2
     on t2.card_id = t1.card_id and
        t2.merchant_id = t1.merchant_id and
        t2.tran_dt >= t1.tran_dt and
        t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id, t1.tran_dt
HAVING count(*) > 2;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fea26/2).

Comment: Customer 1 fails to appear, Customer 3 appears double  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fea26/3

Comment: @davidjhp  . . . I see.  The conditions should only be on the date and not on the transaction.